# como puedo borrar los datos de un Treeview sin borrar estos datos de la base de datos?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

me explico mejor: tengo este TREEVIEW que esta conectado a su base de datos SQLITE, mostrandome los datos siempre alli, pero como puedo hacer para que desaparescan estos datos del treeview sin borrarlos de la base de datos, para poder emitir un documento solo con los datos insertados en ese momento al treeview y no con todos los que ya existentes que carga de la tabla?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias x la ayuda q me puedan brindar porque la verdad no tengo ni idea de como realizar esto, se que debo compartir codigo del avance pero soy muy novato y no se como empezar esto.

> Aqui las llamada y la consulta que siempre seran TRUE como poner FALSE
> en dicha consulta para que solo me imprima los nuevos datos
> insertados?

```
def consulta_orden_compra(self):
            book = self.cuadro_blanco_compra.get_children()
            for elementos in book:
                self.cuadro_blanco_compra.delete(elementos)
            query = "SELECT referencia, cantidad, producto, precio, neto, porciento, itbis, total FROM orden_compra"
            rows = self.run_query(query)#query
            for row in rows:#Row es toda la tabla    
                self.cuadro_blanco_compra.insert('',0, text=row[1], values=row)

def run_query(self,query, tupla=()): #query= es el query de busqueda SQL
        with sqlite3.connect(self.base_datos) as conn: #tupla= recibe los datos dentro de su tupla
            self.cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = self.cursor.execute(query, tupla)
            conn.commit()
            return result
```

Comment: A menos que lo programes explicitamente, no hay nada que mantenga a la base de datos actualizada con respecto al treeview.  Simplemente borra el registro del treeview como si fuera un treeview normal. Averiguar como hacer eso, es algo que deberas hacer por ti mismo para aprender c:

Comment: De hecho, en las primeras tres lineas de consulta_orden_compra estas borrando items del treeview.

Comment: @DanteS. te refieres a?: book = self.cuadro_blanco_compra.get_children() for elementos in book: self.cuadro_blanco_compra.delete(elementos) #si hago esto, borra la lista del treeview, pero aun siguen los datos alli ya que los obtiene de la base de datos. :S la idea es q al borrarlos no los siga cargando de la base de datos, pero si me los siga guardando en la misma.

Comment: Ahhh, lo que buscas es que si se borra un registro del treeview, la proxima llamada a consulta_orden_compra no vuelva a cargar los datos borrados previamente no?

Comment: Perdon, me di cuenta que lo que queria decir implica muchos comentarios. Si es eso lo que buscas, te escribo una respuesta.

Comment: @DanteS. yes.! eso mismo companero

Answer (score 0):

lo pude solucionar pasandole todos los datos de la tabla orden_compra a otra tabla que los ira guardando, asi puedo borrar los datos de orden_compra que son los que aparecen en este Treeview asi esta solo sirve para retener los datos. :D